# java: get byte[] directly from jeditorpane

Tags: java, swing, character-encoding, byte, jeditorpane

I am dealing with a `JEditorPane` with unsupported characters and bytes. If I do `pane.getText().getBytes();` it gives the byte of `�` for any unsupported character so any way of getting bytes from the `JEditorPane` would work.

Comment: *"it gives the byte of � for any unsupported character"*  You think so?  I'm thinking it gives the correct byte but the problem is that the code is *using a font to display it that does not have a symbol for that character.*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *"I wish that were the case"*  I wish it were the case that people read the entire comment and took the hint to post an **MCVE.**  Voting to close.  Without an MCVE, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proper encoding you wish to get bytes for: for example for UTF-8:

```
JEditorPane pane = ....
byte[] data = pane.getText().getBytes("UTF-8");
```